# jammit-s3 conflict with aws-s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, amazon-s3, jammit

If I have both gems I get the error:

```
uninitialized constant AWS::S3::Connection
```

I need both as I'm uploading to S3 with Paperclip and uploading my jammit assets to S3. How to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'jammit-s3', :git => "git://github.com/kmamykin/jammit-s3.git", :branch => "aws-s3"
```